# regular expression extract words from file

Tags: regex

I try to extract words from the string content like

```
export {AbcClient} from ...
export {AdcClient} from ..
```

How to use regular expression to get array of string? In this example is`[AbcClient, AdcClient]`

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What programming language do you use? What is "array of string"?

Comment: For future reference, please tell us which programming language you are using, and also include any code you may have tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most programming languages have the ability to do a regex find all.  In Python, we can try:

```
inp = """export {AbcClient} from ...
export {AdcClient} from .."""

matches = re.findall(r'\bexport \{(.*?)\}', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['AbcClient', 'AdcClient']
```